# Class org.apache.kafka.abstracts.serialization.StringDeserializer could not be found

Tags: apache-kafka

I am working with kafka. and getting the message in the description. I am setting the properties for the deserializer in my consumer class.

```
props.put("key.deserializer",  "org.apache.kafka.abstracts.serialization.StringDeserializer");
props.put("value.deserializer",  "org.apache.kafka.abstracts.serialization.StringDeserializer");

producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
```

Still at runtime i'm getting an error that the deserializer could not be found. We recently upgraded to 10.1.1 from 10.0.1 is there a change in there that I am missing?

Comment: `StringDeserializer.class.getName()` is generally safer, by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka's String deserualizer is
'org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer'

( https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.10.0/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/StringDeserializer.java )