# Unable to get offset lags for kafka. Reason: org.apache.kafka.shaded.common.config.ConfigException

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am testing storm+kafka integration on my local machine. I have storm version 1.2.3 and Kafka 2.5.0. I am using the code from
https://github.com/pvillard31/storm-kafka-kerberos/blob/master/src/main/java/example/KafkaStormKafkaTopology.java
as my testing code.

Whenever I submit topology, I get the following error

```
Unable to get offset lags for kafka. Reason: org.apache.kafka.shaded.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value 
org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer for configuration value.deserializer: 
Class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer could not be found. 
at org.apache.kafka.shaded.common.config.ConfigDef.parseType(ConfigDef.java:671) 
at org.apache.kafka.shaded.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:418) 
at org.apache.kafka.shaded.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:56) 
at org.apache.kafka.shaded.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:63) 
at org.apache.kafka.shaded.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.<init>(ConsumerConfig.java:414) 
at org.apache.kafka.shaded.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:584) 
at org.apache.kafka.shaded.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:566) 
at org.apache.storm.kafka.monitor.KafkaOffsetLagUtil.getOffsetLags(KafkaOffsetLagUtil.java:230) 
at org.apache.storm.kafka.monitor.KafkaOffsetLagUtil.main(KafkaOffsetLagUtil.java:144)
```

Any idea why I am getting this error? And how can I fix this?

I see a similar issue was raised in past in https://stackoverflow.com

[Class org.apache.kafka.abstracts.serialization.StringDeserializer could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50342657/class-org-apache-kafka-abstracts-serialization-stringdeserializer-could-not-be-f)
However, in my case the Deserializer is used as "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"

```
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class org.apache.kafka.abstracts.serialization.StringDeserializer could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50342657/class-org-apache-kafka-abstracts-serialization-stringdeserializer-could-not-be-f)

Comment: You should try using StringDeserializer.class.getName() to prevent typos in the config

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes, i have tried that as well. Did not work

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and figured `storm-kafka-monitor-1.2.3` might be causing the trouble as it uses `maven-shade-plugin` to relocate original kafka packages. Hence `KafkaConsumer` collides at runtime. It's very evident from [pom](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/v1.2.3/external/storm-kafka-monitor/pom.xml).

However, it seems to be addressed in `storm-kafka-monitor-2.0.0`. I am yet to try it, will update my thread if I had some success.